# Tried to fetch document data in firestore subcollection then show this error "Null check operator used on a null value "on flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to fetch document data in firestore subcollection then show this error "Null check operator used on a null value " .
I want to fetch one article in user collection for each users.

[image]

database screenshot

user table

[image]

article subcollection

[image]

all articles UI

[image]

how to fetch a article when click  view button

View button code in All articles UI

```
ElevatedButton(child: Text('View'),onPressed: () {                                                
 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ViewOneUserArticleScreen(id: data[index].id,)));
```

view one article code

```
  Articles? oneArticle;
  bool loading = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    loading = true;
    getArticle();
  }
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();

  Future<void> getArticle() async {

    final id = widget.id;
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/${user?.uid}/articles/$id');
    final snapshot = reference.get();

    final result = await snapshot.then(
        (snap) => snap.data() == null ? null : Articles.fromJson(snap.data()!));

    setState(() {
      oneArticle = result;
      loading = false;
    });
  }
```

model

```
class Articles {
  final  String id;
  final  String topic;
  final  String description;
  final  String url;



  Articles({
    required  this.id,
    required this.topic,
    required  this.description,
    required   this.url
  });

  Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : this(
      id: json['id'],
      topic: json['topic']! as String,
      url: json['url']! as String,
      description: json['description']! as String,
     );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'topic': topic,
      'url': url,
      'description': description,


};
  }



}
```

new error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Issue is in your parsing method, change your `Articles.fromJson` to this:

```
Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : this(
     id: json['id'] ?? '', // <--- change this
     topic: json['topic'] as String ?? '', // <--- change this
     url: json['url'] as String ?? '', // <--- change this
     description: json['description'] as String ?? '', // <--- change this
  );
```

in your json, `topic`, `description` and `url` may be `null` but you used `!` on them and that means you are sure that they aren't null but they are. Also your `id` may be null to but in your object model you set it as `required`, so you need to provide default value to it or just remove the `required` before it.

Comment: now show this error "E/flutter (15427): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' "  I will add SS at the question

Comment: @DasunDola I updated my answer, I think your `id` is null too.

Comment: hey  that's worked. Thank you!! Now I tired to DateTime parameter.   At the "Articles.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)" I added like this "  birthday: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(json['birthday'].toInt() ?? ' '  ) ," but then

Comment: show this error " E/flutter (18747): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Timestamp' has no instance method 'toInt'. " do you know how to solve

Comment: this is a different issue but you can try this: `birthday: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(json['birthday'] ?? 0) `

Comment: Thank you for your support bro !!! now show this error "Null check operator used on a null value"

Comment: can you open new question so I can see your code?